# Google Sheets: Formula in an Array in a Formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to find a way to consolidate formulas into 1 cell. As of right now i have 2 mildly complicated formulas using up multiple columns.

I'm trying to put the formulas as an array in a single cell.

To avoid confusing the matter, i've only included a simplified version of the formulas and only using 1 column.

Edit:

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o8lJ4SZVKvv7bztPH3adrdZ7SZbkPLb93q0oi_Yj0vI/edit?usp=sharing) is the Spreadsheet in question, the Better Mobs sheet

Ok, so i tried to implement the solution and it didn't work the way i needed. Before i consolidate and just use 1 spreadsheet, the full formula in cell F1 is:

```
=match(max(F2:F),F2:F,0)+1&" - "&INDIRECT("A"&match(max(F2:F),F2:F,0)+1)
```

and cell F2 is:

```
=IFERROR(E269/ROUNDUP($C269/MAX(0,importrange("1rkS5zujl6oo66JNbhb8yWOjgOqRoXhvyGa-nr95krJ4","Damage Reward!$B$26")/2-$K269)*MAX((MIN(100+sqrt(importrange("1rkS5zujl6oo66JNbhb8yWOjgOqRoXhvyGa-nr95krJ4","Damage Reward!$B$27"))-sqrt(O269)-MAX($B269-importrange("1rkS5zujl6oo66JNbhb8yWOjgOqRoXhvyGa-nr95krJ4","Damage Reward!$B$3"),0)*5,100)/100),0)*2),"")
```

Comment: i found the problem in the formula for F2. E269/roundup(formula,max(formula,0))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want in cell C1:

`={MAX(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(B2:B*D2:D/E2:E)));ArrayFormula(IFERROR(B2:B*D2:D/E2:E))}`

Comment: Yes! It provided an array of all the values where they were (C2, C3, etc) so i tried just =MAX(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(B2:B*D2:D/E2:E))) and it worked perfect.